# Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `English'

Tags: texlive, hyphenation, polyglossia

I'm running Arch Linux and installed texlive 2013 via `tlmgr`.

My file is this:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Running `xelatex` on my file yields this:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `English'
(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 6.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \adddialect
```

I have consulted the other answers dealing with similar problems. Most concern babel, which I am not using. Some suggest installing a language, but this error only concerns english (and I installed collection-langenglish anyway).  I tried running `tlmgr fmtutil --all`, but this changes nothing.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What did you install exactly? If you installed the default, full distribution, you would certainly have `collection-langenglish` with no need to install it specially. Your code compiles fine here with TeX Live 2013 installed from upstream on Arch.

Comment: As explained in response to your other question, it is recommended to install a scheme. Preferably `full` but, failing that, a smaller, complete scheme. Installing things piecemeal like this is a recipe for frustration. If you insist, you will have to examine your `.log` files carefully. Any particular reason you want to inflict this specific form of penance on yourself?

Comment: I've just read what the wiki says about the net install and I can therefore understand why you might be trying to do this. However, I believe that the advice in the wiki is misguided at best. Yes, it is possible to do it that way but it will require either considerable knowledge of TeX or a great deal of time and patience. The fact that you are asking these questions tells me that the former does not apply. (You may know a great deal about *using* TeX but this is about the way an installation works.) Whether you have enough of the latter to spare I don't know. To me, the full scheme *is* KISS.

Comment: I just installed scheme-full, and the code compiles, so I'll just leave it at that. My main reason for trying to install packages piece by piece was to see if I could better learn what was going on (a strategy that works pretty well for Arch Linux as a whole), but I suppose the difference is that Arch is really only recommended for those with linux experience (which I have), whereas I have very little experience constructing any actually complex LaTeX/XeTeX doucments (and little at all with TeX per se) and don't need to do anything fantastically complicated anyway.

Comment: The other is that `pacman` is designed to handle dependencies brilliantly whereas `tlmgr` is not designed to handle them at all. If you want to learn how it works, one good way is to read the console output and look in the log files from compilations. (Especially those which don't work as you expect!) Also try adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` to see exactly which files a document requires for compilation.

Comment: I'm getting this error trying to build polyglossia with the initial `xelatex polyglossia.dtx`; any clues?

Comment: I think I could fix the error by adding `texlive-babel` and rebuilding the xelatex format with: `fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex`. I also have all the hyphenation packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `texlive-hyphen-*` packages.

On Fedora that would be achieved by:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-hyphen-*
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on such error while attempting to fix the `texlive-polyglossia` package of GNU Guix.  The base texlive package there is quite minimal and doesn't include all the formats with hyphenation support, so I had to add all the hyphenation packages and babel to the environment and rebuild the format I was interested in:

```
fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex
```

The main issue in my case was the lack of the babel package in the build environment.  I've finally managed to have it built, and here are the various Guix TexLive packages and fonts that were needed:

```
(native-inputs (list fontconfig     ;for XDG_DATA_DIRS (to locate fonts)
                         font-amiri
                         font-dejavu
                         font-gfs-ambrosia
                         font-gnu-freefont
                         font-linuxlibertine
                         font-sil-ezra
                         texlive-latex-base
                         texlive-babel
                         texlive-bin    ;for fmtutil.cnf
                         texlive-bidi
                         texlive-booktabs
                         texlive-caption
                         texlive-context
                         texlive-cm
                         texlive-latex-fancyvrb
                         texlive-etoolbox
                         texlive-fonts-latex
                         texlive-fontspec
                         texlive-hyphen-base
                         texlive-hyphen-afrikaans
                         texlive-hyphen-ancientgreek
                         texlive-hyphen-armenian
                         texlive-hyphen-basque
                         texlive-hyphen-belarusian
                         texlive-hyphen-bulgarian
                         texlive-hyphen-catalan
                         texlive-hyphen-chinese
                         texlive-hyphen-churchslavonic
                         texlive-hyphen-coptic
                         texlive-hyphen-croatian
                         texlive-hyphen-czech
                         texlive-hyphen-danish
                         texlive-hyphen-dutch
                         texlive-hyphen-english
                         texlive-hyphen-esperanto
                         texlive-hyphen-estonian
                         texlive-hyphen-ethiopic
                         texlive-hyphen-finnish
                         texlive-hyphen-schoolfinnish
                         texlive-hyphen-french
                         texlive-hyphen-friulan
                         texlive-hyphen-galician
                         texlive-hyphen-georgian
                         texlive-hyphen-german
                         texlive-hyphen-greek
                         texlive-hyphen-hungarian
                         texlive-hyphen-icelandic
                         texlive-hyphen-indic
                         texlive-hyphen-indonesian
                         texlive-hyphen-interlingua
                         texlive-hyphen-irish
                         texlive-hyphen-italian
                         texlive-hyphen-kurmanji
                         texlive-hyphen-latin
                         texlive-hyphen-latvian
                         texlive-hyphen-lithuanian
                         texlive-hyphen-macedonian
                         texlive-hyphen-mongolian
                         texlive-hyphen-norwegian
                         texlive-hyphen-occitan
                         texlive-hyphen-pali
                         texlive-hyphen-piedmontese
                         texlive-hyphen-polish
                         texlive-hyphen-portuguese
                         texlive-hyphen-romanian
                         texlive-hyphen-romansh
                         texlive-hyphen-russian
                         texlive-hyphen-sanskrit
                         texlive-hyphen-serbian
                         texlive-hyphen-slovak
                         texlive-hyphen-slovenian
                         texlive-hyphen-spanish
                         texlive-hyphen-swedish
                         texlive-hyphen-thai
                         texlive-hyphen-turkish
                         texlive-hyphen-turkmen
                         texlive-hyphen-ukrainian
                         texlive-hyphen-uppersorbian
                         texlive-hyphen-welsh
                         texlive-latex-graphics
                         texlive-hyperref
                         texlive-kpathsea ;for cp227.tcx & friends
                         texlive-lm
                         texlive-makecmds
                         texlive-metalogo
                         texlive-microtype
                         texlive-paralist
                         texlive-latex-tools
                         texlive-latex-xkeyval
                         texlive-stringenc
                         texlive-tex-ini-files ;for pdftexconfig
                         texlive-zapfding
                         texlive-zref))
```

I hope that helps.